# Why would you use a signed message to verify the sender?

Tags: signature, recover

In the [Ghost contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x160c404b2b49cbc3240055ceaee026df1e8497a0#code) they have:

```
    function mint(uint8 quantity, bytes calldata signature)
        public
        payable
        callerIsUser
    {
        require(DA_ACTIVE == true, "DA isnt active");
        if (!directMintAllowed) {
            require(
                daSigner ==
                    keccak256(
                        abi.encodePacked(
                            "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",
                            bytes32(uint256(uint160(msg.sender)))
                        )
                    ).recover(signature),
                "Signer address mismatch."
            );
        }
        ...
    }
```

I feel like I'm missing something. Isn't this equivalent:

```
    function mint(uint8 quantity)
        public
        payable
        callerIsUser
    {
        require(DA_ACTIVE == true, "DA isnt active");
        if (!directMintAllowed) {
            require(daSigner == msg.sender, "Signer address mismatch.");
        }
        ...
    }
```

What is the value in adding a signed message check here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not at all equivalent :

```
require(
         daSigner ==
             keccak256(
                 abi.encodePacked(
                     "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",
                     bytes32(uint256(uint160(msg.sender)))
                 )
             ).recover(signature),
         "Signer address mismatch."
);
```

Ensures that `signature` refers to a signed message from `daSigner` with a content set to the address of `msg.sender`.

Anyone holding a signed message from `daSigner`  containing their address can pass this check. `daSigner` can give rights to any address of its choice to mint by signing the appropriate message. The user then takes that signature to the smart contracts and is allowed to mint. In that case, `daSigner` authorized a user to mint, but the user is paying the fees as he would be interacting with the contract.

In the second case :

```
require(daSigner == msg.sender, "Signer address mismatch.");
```

Ensures that `msg.sender` is `daSigner` Only `daSigner` can pass this check. In that case, `daSigner` would mint for a user and pay the fees.

Comment: Ah I see! This means that `daSigner` could sign a message for any other address (i.e. the other person who would be invoking `mint` would be `msg.sender` ) and with that the contract verifies that `daSigner` has approved them to mint.